# Overwrite namespace usage in extended class in PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, namespaces

### Overwrite namespace usage in extended class

Is it possible to overwrite the used namespace of the parent class without rewriting the function in the extended class?

For clarification i write down an example:

i have two classes like this:

```
namespace one;
class hey
{
    public static function say()
    {
        echo "hey";
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace two;
class hey
{
    public static function say()
    {
        echo "ho";
    }
}
```

Now i use on of the namespaces in this class:

```
use one\hey;
class saysomething
{
    public static function main()
    {
        hey::say();
    }
}
```

Now i want to extend the last class:

```
class extended extends saysomething
{
}

extended::main();
```

In this class i want to use namespace "two\one" without overwriting the function, is it possible? *f it is, how?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, rewriting what function?

Comment: `use one\hey as heyone;`?

Comment: In the class "saysomething" i have used the namespace "one\hey". I dont want to change that. 
In the next class "extended" i want to have the namespace "two\hey" used instead.

Comment: This is a case where dependency injection must clearly used.. depending on your needs you can inject the class from namespace one or two..

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now.  You're trying to some kind of conditional inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

You must define `extended::main()` within `extended` class, like this:

```
use two\hey;

class extended extends saysomething
{
    public static function main()
    {
        hey::say(); // will call two/hey::say method
    }
}
```

Namespaces won't help here.